# ASP Classico: Como substituir o caractere "TRAVESSÃO" por "TRAÇO"?

Tags: asp, replace

estou com um problema - ao utilizar um componente para PDF - acabei tendo um erro de "Out of Range" na hora de gerar o documento PDF.

pelo erro e linha descobri onde estava o problema - e identifiquei que o erro era pq o usuario cadastrou um "TRAVESSÃO" no campo buscado.

ao trocar o "TRAVESSAO" por "TRAÇO" - tudo voltou ao normal.

Obviamente o erro no componente ocorre pq ele nao identifica o "TRAVESSAO" como um caractere de "Tabela" - ja q ele inclusive nao faz parte do teclado padrao.

Em milhares de cadastros foi a primeira vez q tive esse problema - mas como é comum os clientes usarem o traço para separar as informacoes do campo, (e acredito que o problema ocorreu pq o CORRETOR ORTOGRAFICO trocou automaticamente o traço pelo travessao) - queria uma solucao para o problema.

Essa solucao é simples..

basta verificar o dado enviado no cadastro e trocar o TRAVESSAO por TRAÇO usando o comando "REPLACE"

```
REPLACE(texto, "TRAVESSAO", "TRAÇO")
```

minha duvida é - como eu informo o "TRAVESSAO" no codigo - ja q ele nao existe no teclado.

valeu!!

Comment: Sem saber que tipo de caractere é esse TRAVESSÃO fica muito difícil. Já pensou em fazer o inverso? Por ex: Filtrar apenas os caracteres aceitáveis na busca.

Comment: Travessão no Windows AltGr + Num- ou Alt + CTRL + Num- (ou Alt + 0151)  OBS: Num- é a tecla de “menos” no painel das teclas numéricas assim como 0151 também. No meu teclado funcionou Alt + 0151  olha ele ai   — é maior que o Meia-risca –  ou - (tracinho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travessão no Windows   `AltGr + Num-` ou   `Alt + CTRL + Num-` ou   `Alt + 0151`

OBS: Num- é a tecla de “menos” no painel das teclas numéricas assim como 0151 também. No meu teclado funcionou Alt + 0151 olha ele ai — é maior que o Meia-risca – ou - (tracinho).

No Mac OS X   `Alt + hífen`

```
REPLACE(texto, "—", "-")
```

Eu já usei muitos replaces em asp assim: `REPLACE(texto, chr(151), "-")` Traço pode ser chr(150) ou chr(45)

```
           glifo    Unicode          HTML    TeX         Windows    Mac OS
hífen        -      U+2012 (8210)   nenhum    -        Alt + 0045   
meia-risca   –      U+2013 (8211)   &ndash;   --       Alt + 0150   Option + -
travessão    —      U+2014 (8212)   &mdash;   ---      Alt + 0151   Shift + Option + -
```

Alguns teclados não tem painel das teclas numéricas, como fazer?

> Copie o Travessão — e cole-o no seu código!!

[Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travess%C3%A3o)

Comment: Oi @leo-caracciolo, primeira obrigado pela ajuda!! Era isso mesmo que precisava! Meu teclado não tem o alfnum e por algum motivo usando o Chr(151) no replace ele nao estava fazendo a troca. Mas deu tudo certo usando o caracter direto. Obrigado!! Daniel